# How can I prevent the height of this navbar increasing when I scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I have a floating horizontal navbar positioned using jQuery. It's perfect when the page is static, but as soon as I start scrolling, the navbar's height increases and I am unsure why.

[I've a JSFiddle here to show the unwanted effect](http://jsfiddle.net/aywfj5bf/5/)

Here's the html

```
<div id="stickyribbon">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="1_Lesson.html" target="_blank">Week1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="2_Lesson.html" target="_blank">Week2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="3_Lesson.html" target="_blank">Week3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="4_Lesson.html" target="_blank">Week4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="5_Lesson.html" target="_blank">Week5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="6_Lesson.html" target="_blank">Week6</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css

```
#stickyribbon {
    width:800px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
#stickyribbon ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#stickyribbon li {
    display:table-cell;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#stickyribbon li a {
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#stickyribbon li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
```

And lastly the JavaScript

```
$(function () {
    var stickyRibbonTop = $('#stickyribbon').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyRibbonTop) {
            $('#stickyribbon').css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top: '0px'
            });
        } else {
            $('#stickyribbon').css({
                position: 'static',
                top: '0px'
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'd be grateful for any guidance, as I'm completely stumped.
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your CSS to the below, crucially you need to correctly define positioning, padding and margins to establish the layout in both states:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aywfj5bf/8/)

```
#stickyribbon {
    width:800px;
    background: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position:static;
    top:0;
    margin:15px 0;
}
#stickyribbon ul {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#stickyribbon li {
    display:table-cell;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding:0 40px;
}
#stickyribbon li a {
    display:block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#stickyribbon li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The div #stickyribbon has some margin and when the page is scrolled, the div is redrawn to fill that margin.
Add
margin:0;
to #stickyribbon ul and #stickyribbon li.